# no module named 'keras', 'pandas' in spyder

Tags: python

I have old code using `keras` instead of `tf.keras`. I am running on my conda environment with tensorflow 2 and python 3.8 installed.  I installed keras using `conda install -c conda-forge keras` and installed pandas using `conda install pandas`. Then when I ran the below code in spyder, I got errors of `no module named pandas` and `no module named 'keras'`. Where did I do wrong? Thanks for helping.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras

```
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential,Model
```

Comment: There are lots of things that could cause this. Start by checking that you're using the right conda environment with `conda info --envs`. The one you're using will have an asterisk next to it.

Comment: You can also make sure you're using the right Python interpreter with `import sys;
sys.executable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure you are using the Anaconda version of python. At the command line type `which python` and verify you are using the Anaconda version.

Comment: Thanks jmh, yes i am using anaconda python, see this below infor. any suggestion? Thanks  (base) C:\Users\ygn>where.exe python
C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3\python.exe

Comment: Try to run your python file like this: C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3\python3.exe yourfile.py

Comment: thanks guys, I got help from Ash and it was due to using different python and also spyder was installed using pip install. I changed to use conda install spyder. then it is solved. Thanks guys. Have a great day!